# Node teasers break my layout

Tags: wysiwyg, nodes

Node teasers are breaking my layout by not closing div and span tags.

The nodes are being written using WYSIWYG and CKEditor 3.4.2.6041.

An example of this broken layout is:
http://www.energyjustice.net/node?page=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably `Correct faulty and chopped off HTML` is not checked in the input format used. Goto `admin/config/content/formats` and then look at the format used for this and make sure that it's last, eg:

[image]

If this doesn't work, check out [How to get teaser break to work with WYSIWYG + CKEDITOR?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8643/how-to-get-teaser-break-to-work-with-wysiwyg-ckeditor?rq=1) for more things to look into.